# How do you drop a `references` column in rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I've created a table with a `references` column in an earlier migration and now I would like to drop it. I know I can do a call to `remove_column` on the generated name, but is there a way to remove it using the the table name instead?

`remove_references :blah, :users` instead of `remove_column :blah, :user_id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the method aptly named [remove_references](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Table.html#M000212), as you guessed. It only needs one parameter, same as `references` needs one parameter too:

From the API documentation:

```
remove_references(*args)

#Removes a reference. Optionally removes a type column. remove_references and
#remove_belongs_to are acceptable.
Examples

 t.remove_references(:goat)
 t.remove_references(:goat, :polymorphic => true)
 t.remove_belongs_to(:goat)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no special method to do so. When you come to think about this it makes perfect sense, since the `references` method doesn't actually create a foreign constraint in the db, meaning that this generated column isn't special at all.

**Update**

As @Zabba noted there seems to be a [remove_references](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Table.html#M000212) method. I've never seen it used in practice, but its description sounds about right.